# Getting mingw-get to install correctly - mingw/msys path missing plus more!

Tags: c++, windows-xp, g++, mingw, msys

I'm running windows XP.

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and so downloading mingw-get-inst [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst).

I've done this a couple times and the last time I checked boes to install EVERYTHING including, but not limited to, gcc, g++, MSYS and the MinGW Compiling Suite.  I told it to make a program menu shortcut, too.

I believe I have correctly added MinGW/bin to the Environment Settings' *Path*.

So I have the shortcut to the MSYS shell now.  It goes to C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat, but the whole msys directory does not exist!

There are tons of "packages" have been downloaded as far as I can tell ("mingw-get show" brings up a lot!), but it doesn't seem like any of it installed correctly.

Also, should I be able to use commands like "g++ foo.cpp -o foo.exe" from cmd.exe or only from the MSYS shell?  Because I was unable to use cmd.exe.

Please help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The MSYS and MinGW installation procedure is a nightmare, and has got worse over the years. If you just want the compiler suite (no UNIX tools like sed, grep), then I suggest you go to [Twilight Dragon Media](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) and download GCC from there. If you also want all the tools, including the Bash shell, the easiest way I've found to get them is to install [Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) (which you may want anyway), which includes them all. And if you want a C++ IDE that works well with GCC, take a look at [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

Comment: Works great! I had a small test.cpp waiting and it compiled fine, suprised that _my_ code compiled, but it did!

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, mingw is easier usin the embedded version in Git. But it does not provide mingw-get?! It there a way to install any package manager tool?

Answer (score 2):

What is the result of running, at a `cmd.exe` prompt, the command `echo %Path%`?  It should (given what you wrote about your system) include “`C:\MinGW\bin`”—does it?

What is the result of running `dir C:\MinGW`?

Note that `mingw-get show` shows details of *available* packages—those mingw-get knows how to download and install.  The installer is a bit primitive, but has gotten better over the last year or so.

Answer (score 0):

If you issue the command $ echo $PATH, you'll notice it contains /mingw/bin  But the /mingw directory is unavailable.  To mount it, edit the MSYS fstab, adding a line like C:\MinGW /mingw  For details, see the MingW [Getting Started](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) guide, more specifically section "After Installing You Should..."

You only need to add MinGW/bin to the Windows' Environment Settings' Path if you plan to use MingW's executables outside of MSYS.