# Objective C program Compilation and Execution

Tags: objective-c, shell, gcc, gnustep

I am a newbie to Objective C programs. I'm learning to code from tutorialspoint.com 
As mentioned therein I downloaded GNUstep (Windows).
First, installed the MSYS/MinGW System package and then core package.
After that followed the steps mentioned there. I created a simple program with name hello.m and Stored that in C drive **(Snapshot 1)**
I don't know the meaning of this command below but entered it:

$ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries hello.m -o hello -lgnustep-base -lobjc

The error it shows is - sh: gcc: command not found

Please help with the same, to compile and run my first Objective C program

Comment: @deimus As you said I have downloaded TDM-GCC (and installed) from the link you provided. Now during compilation of my file it shows -

"gcc.exe: error: hello.m: No such file or directory"

Is there any specific location at which I should place the file ??

Where I am going wrong ?? Please help

Comment: You should run the compilation command from the same directory where the `hello.m` file is.

Comment: @deimus I have stored the files of GNUstep and that of TDM GCC @ C:\ (C drive)
and I have created a folder in C directory called "Project" (in which I have stored file hello.m).
So, basically GNUstep, TDM-GCC and the Project folder lies at the same location i.e. C:\.  


My command is -
$ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries hello.m -o hello -lgnustep-base -lobjc

What changes should I make here ??

Comment: navigate to the folder where the `hello.m` file is with `cd` command and run the same compilation command from there

Comment: @deimus Yeah, did that. I navigated to that folder where my file hello.m is stored by 'cd' command. After that again when I put -

$ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries hello.m -o hello -lgnustep-base -lobjc


Now it shows
gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

I would be really helpful if you get me out of this mess...:)

Comment: man, this is already out of the scope of your question here, please try to find and fix small problems on your own, and in case your stuck somewhere ask another question here. Sorry but I've to go home already, its Friday ;) Happy weekend ! Also have a look at this step by step guideline on who to compile objective-c code on Windows http://sweettutos.com/2012/08/11/objective-c-on-windows-yes-you-can/

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` is the compiler, the other parameters are for compiling `objective-c` code.

Apparently you have misconfiguration in `MSYS/MinGW` setup.

Check out following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953307/getting-mingw-get-to-install-correctly-mingw-msys-path-missing-plus-more) which has alternative and easier solution for running `gcc` under Windows.